# From month to month and year

Tags: php

For example, I have the month 13 and I want to convert it to 1 year and 1 month with php.
26 - 2 years and 2 months.
How to "convert" it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$totalmonths = 26;
$years = floor($totalmonths/12);
$months = $totalmonths % 12;
echo $years, " year", $years==1?"":"s";
if ($months != 0)
    echo " and ", $months, "month", $months==1?"":"s";
```

Answer (score 1):

Divide by 12 and take integer part and modulus separately.

Comment: i tried this.Number 16 - 1.333(3).But it's 1 year and 4 months